# Is there a toggle for hover or mouseenter/mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some div element which each one contains a few div elements inside.  So I want to give effect these div element in hover.  I am not sure to use hover or mouseenter. For example in hover of a div, it must run an animate am move to left or change its color. But the effect stays even when I move the mouse somewhere else, which it isnt what I want.  I want it to be working like css hover which moves back after mouseleave.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/5/)**

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").hide();
    $(".ln, .gw, .mc, .rt").hover(function(){
        var classname = $(this).parent();
        var name = $(classname).children(':first-child').next();

        $(name).animate({
            "margin-left": "100px"                        
         }, 500);

        $(classname).find(".close").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item1">
    <div class="name1 ln">name 1</div>
    <div class="name2 ln">name 2</div>
    <div class="name3 ln">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
    <div class="name4 gw">name 1</div>
    <div class="name5 gw">name 2</div>
    <div class="name6 gw">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div class="item3">
    <div class="name7 mc">name 1</div>
    <div class="name8 mc">name 2</div>
    <div class="name9 mc">name 3</div>
    <div class="close mc">close</div>
</div>
<div class="item4">
    <div class="name10 rt">name 1</div>
    <div class="name11 rt">name 2</div>
    <div class="name12 rt">name 3</div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What about this http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/9/.

Comment: @Danko Thanks your code seems the best so far, if you post it as an answer I would approve it.

Comment: @Danko just one small problem. It operates as soon as I hover the whole item. How can I make it working only when the second div of the item is hover ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can first add another class on all items like `.item` to target each one and then just the second div with jquery, try this:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    $(this).find('div').eq(1).hover(function(){
      var name = $(this);
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
          $(name).stop().animate({
           "margin-left": "100px"                        
          }, 500);
        } else {
          $(name).stop().animate({
           "margin-left": "0"                        
          }, 500);
        }
      $(this).parent().find(".close").stop(true,true).fadeToggle(500);
    })
 })
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/18/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").hide();
    $(".ln, .gw, .mc, .rt").hover(function(){
        var classname = $(this).parent();
        var name = $(classname).children(':first-child').next();

        $(name).stop();
        $(name).animate({
            "margin-left": "100px"                        
         }, 500);

        $(classname).find(".close").stop();
        $(classname).find(".close").fadeIn(500);
    }, function(){
        var classname = $(this).parent();
        var name = $(classname).children(':first-child').next();

        $(name).stop();
        $(name).animate({
            "margin-left": "0px"                        
         }, 500);

        $(classname).find(".close").stop();
        $(classname).find(".close").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

as jQuery code.
fixed it ;)

Comment: Thanks, It seems working but it keep repeating the animation couple of times. why is that? DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/11/

Comment: @user3229902 It's because without `.stop`s the animations queue up, waiting for the one before to stop before it starts

Comment: thanks Zach Saucier for being polite enough to explain it, I've improved the code and hope it works just like user3229902 wants it to

Comment: @Renze thanks for your update. it works well, but it does not show the .close div. Why is that ?

Comment: @user3229902 Because he used `fadeOut` on it. My version is the exact same but leaves doesn't have the fadeout and is more concise

Comment: @user3229902 that's because i typed fint instead of find, editing it right now

Comment: or if you're looking for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Renze/nBuB4/ , feel free to use it

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").hide();
    $(".ln, .gw, .mc, .rt").hover(function () {
        console.log('working');
        var classname = $(this).parent();
        var name = $(classname).children(':first-child').next();

        $(name).stop().animate({
            "margin-left": "100px"                        
         }, 500);

        $(classname).find(".close").fadeIn(500);
    }, function () {
        console.log('workign2');
        var classname = $(this).parent();
        var name = $(classname).children(':first-child').next();

        $(name).stop().animate({
            "margin-left": "0px"                        
         }, 500);
        $(classname).find(".close").fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/10/)

Comment: Thanks its similar to what I want, but there are two problems. How can I fadeOut the .close class too in the callback ?! and secondly, when I hover the item, it sometimes move back when it has not even completed the animation, so it might seem kinda buggy. Any way to fix these?

Comment: @user3229902 The first note is fixed by adding a `fadeOut`... The second I am unable to recreate. I added [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)s so that it doesn't queue up and closes when the hover is stopped. If you don't want that behavior then remove the `.stop`s

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `toggleClass`

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3TeY/20/)